# Greedy Algorithm minimum basestation

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Suppose we have a set of houses on one side of a long street to be served by electric
distribution boxes that can connect houses up to distance d. We need to use the
minimum number of boxes. Show how to position the electric distribution boxes.

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: This is the question

Comment: No, this is a command. Please read [ask].

Comment: This question should be closed. Seems to be about doing homework for someone. However, not a single line code is provided.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove the correctness of a greedy algorithm, we must show that it produces a valid answer, has the greedy choice property, and that the problem has optimal substructure. The greedy choice property states that the first decision made by the algorithm can ALWAYS be a choice in an optimal solution. Optimal substructure means that the optimal solution to a given problem contains optimal solutions each sub problem.

For this answer, I am going to assume that you can only place an electrical distribution box at a house, rather than between them. I will also assume that each house at most d away from the houses adjacent to it.

Let current_distance be the distance from the previous box (or from the first house on the street at the beginning of the algorithm)

While there are houses without electricity
    While (current_distance <= d)
         If we can move to the next house before we are more than d away from last box 
           (i.e. current_distance + distance_to_next_house <= d) then move to the next 
            house
         else place a box at the current house

Essentially what this algorithm does is move as far as possible from the previous box, then places a new box. Then it goes as far as it can from the last box, and repeats until all houses are within d of an electrical distribution box.

First let's make sure that our solution is valid and provides each house with electricity. Assume that it is not valid, and there is at least one house hi that is x away from an electrical distribution box placed at hk, where x > d. 
Because the distance between hi and hk is greater than d, we know that there must be at least one house hj between them such that the distance between hi and hj <= d. Because our algorithm will only place a box at a house that is <= d away from the previous box, we know that this is not possible and our algorithm will always produce a valid solution.

Next let's prove the greedy choice property. Assume O is the optimal solution set of houses to place boxes at, such that size(O) is minimum. Suppose the first box in O, o1, is not at the same house that our algorithm would choose, h1. We know that h1 is further down the street than o1, because our algorithm always chooses the furthest house to place a box at. We also know that the distance from o1 to o2 is less than or equal to d, and let's call this distance d0. Because h1 is further down the street than o1, we know that the distance between h1 and o2 (call this dh) is less than du. This means that dh < du <= d. Therefore, we can replace o1 with h1, which means that the first choice of our algorithm could always be a choice in an optimal solution. We have proven the greedy choice property.

Finally let's prove that this problem has optimal substructures. We can do this by proving that for any box placed, our algorithm will be further down, or at the same place, on the street as any optimal solution. After we prove this, we must show that the size of our algorithms solution is the same size as the optimal solution. Let the optimal solution be called O (where each house chosen for a box is 01, o2, ..., on), and let the solution created by our algorithm be called H (where each house is h1,h2, ..., hn).

We know our first choice can always be a part of the optimal solution, so h1 must always be further along than, or at the same house as o1.
Assume that hk is further along than, or at the same house as ok. 
Now let's prove that hk+1 must be further or at the same point on the street as ok+1.
Assume that this is not true, and that ok+1 is further along than hk+1. Let dx represent the distance between ok and ok+1, dy represent the distance between hk and hk+1, and dz represent the distance between hk+1 and ok+1. We know that dx <= d. We also know that dy +dz <= dx, therefore dy + dz <= d, so our algorithm would not have stopped at hk+1, and would have continued to at least ok+1. Therefore hk+1 must be at the same point, or further than, ok+1.

We know that size(H) can't be less than the size(O), because O is the optimal solution. To prove size(O) = size(H), first assume that size(O) < size(H). We know that for any k, hk is as far as, or further than, ok. However, the size of our set is larger than the size of O, so we must have extra boxes placed after hk. Now let k=size(O), so ok is the last house with a box in O. We know that the distance between ok and the last house on the street (call this dz) is less than or equal to d. But since our algorithm is always ahead of or equal to the optimal solution, we know that the distance between hk and the last house on the street (dh), must be less than or equal to dz. Therefore dh <= dz <= d. This means that our algorithm would not place a box between hk and the final house, and the size of H is equal to the size of O, and is then a minimum size.

Here we have proven that our algorithm produces a valid answer, has the greedy choice property, and has optimal substructures. Therefore, we have produced a correct algorithm for this problem.